# Put a method as value in a map

Tags: java

I want to use map in console menu and put methods that returns `void` as a value, and my methods print several times to the console. Is this possible to do?

Comment: By "returns Void as a value" are you talking about the [`java.lang.Void` class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Void.html) or just `public void something(){}`?

Comment: just public void something(){}

Answer (score 3):

Encapsulate each method inside an object (a Runnable for example):

```
Map<String, Runnable> commands = new HashMap<String, Runnable>();
commands.put("foo", new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello foo");
    }
});
commands.put("bar", new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Hello bar");
    }
});
```

Comment: encapsulate is an idea)